# Regular expression along with a header line

Tags: regex

I have a pattern like below

```
ServerA:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  Running
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running

ServerB:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  stopped
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running

ServerC:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  stopped
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running
```

I am able to capture the process and the status of the process using below Regex

```
.*^(\w+).*[)]\s+(.*)\n
```

But i want to capture the Server name as well. But if i try to add

`(.*):port:(.*)\n` to above expression, its only including the first process. How is this possible ?

So idea is to have a expression which can find processes which are stopped and to capture the server name along with the error so that it looks more meaning full.

We have a very big list of servers and their Port status along with process status. Can some one have a look at this ?

EDIT : This is an example, In real case we will have different number of process for each servers ( Some might have 3 processes, some will have 4, some 6 ).

Comment: what environment are you using?

Comment: Writing a dedicated parsing method might turn out a better idea than using regex. A single regex approach for this kind of task may work with Python PyPi regex module, or .NET regex, where you can access all captures within a single group.

Comment: @NickParsons This Regex is being used in a monitoring tool which monitor the log files using the regex we provide.

Comment: which language is the monitoring tool developed?

Comment: Please [edit] this post to indicate which tool or platform you are using, in accordance with the [requirements for the `regex` tag.](/tags/regex/info) There are many regex dialects and implementations. The common-ground basic regex simply cannot do what you are asking, if I understand your question correctly (viz. reuse the beginning of the match for subsequent matches below the same heading).

Comment: @tripleee I am using a custom tool, which has capability to monitor text files, and i am trying to create regular expression to suite this need.

Comment: Then if this custom tool has nonstandard regex facilities, you need to describe them. Can it match across line boundaries? Does it support Perl extensions like lookaheads?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array containing all you need using this regex.
Runs globally with multi-line flag.

`(?m)(?:^(.*?):port:[ \t]*(.*)|(?!\A)\G)\s*^(\S+).*[)][ \t]*(.*)`

https://regex101.com/r/ncUC0k/1

which produces a nice array you can sift through

```
[
  [ServerA , OK , Process1 , Running],
  [        ,    , Process2 , Running],
  [ServerB , OK , Process1 , Stopped],
  [        ,    , Process2 , Running],
  [        ,    , Process3 , Running],
  [        ,    , Process4 , Running],
  [        ,    , Process5 , Running],
  [ServerC , OK , Process1 , Stopped],
  [        ,    , Process2 , Running],
  [ServerD , OK , Process1 , Stopped],
]
```

Regex comments

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode
 (?:                           # Cluster
      ^                             # BOL
      ( .*? )                       # (1), Server
      :port:
      [ \t]*                        # trim
      ( .* )                        # (2), Port statis

   |                              # or,

      (?! \A )                      # Not BOS
      \G                            # Start where last match left off
 )                             # ---------
 \s*                           # Many whitespace
 ^                             # BOL
 ( \S+ )                       # (3), Process
 .* 
 [)]                           # last ')'
 [ \t]*                        # trim
 ( .* )                        # (4), Process status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?:^(.*):port:(?:.*)$)(?:\n.*\n*)\K(?:^(\w+).*[(](\w+)[)] +(?:stopped)$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J1u1SW/1)

Comment: Your Regex worked, But it worked only where there is 2 processes, Our case is some servers will have 3 process, some will have 6 processes. Then how can we handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Perl one-liner solution

```
$ cat unitedartinc.txt
ServerA:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  Running
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running

ServerB:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  stopped
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running

ServerC:port: OK
Process1         Description              processname     (processno)  stopped
Process2         Description              processname     (processno)  Running
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while(/(^.+?):port:(.+?)(\n\n|\Z)/msg ) { $x=$1;$y=$2; while($y=~/(^\w+).+?[)]\s+(\S+)$/gms) { print "$x-$1-$2\n" }} ' unitedartinc.txt
ServerA-Process1-Running
ServerA-Process2-Running
ServerB-Process1-stopped
ServerB-Process2-Running
ServerC-Process1-stopped
ServerC-Process2-Running
$
```

or - this one

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while(/(^.+?):port:(.+?)(?-s:(?=^.+?:port)|\Z)/msg ) { $x=$1;$y=$2; while($y=~/(^\w+).+?[)]\s+(\S+)$/gms) { print "$x-$1-$2\n" }} ' unitedartinc.txt
ServerA-Process1-Running
ServerA-Process2-Running
ServerB-Process1-stopped
ServerB-Process2-Running
ServerC-Process1-stopped
ServerC-Process2-Running
$
```